# Webpack fails to find module dirs

Tags: webpack

I have a React project where the root dir has an `app` directory. Inside the `app` directory, there is a `containers` and a `components` directory. How do I change the following so that webpack actually looks in the directory where my entry point is, for modules.

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const PATHS = {
  app: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
  build: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
};

module.exports = {
  // where to start bundling
  entry: [
    './app/app.js',
  ],

  // where to output
  output: {
    // output to same dir
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: 'timbundle.js',
  },
```

Comment: I don’t see the relevance of Brainfuck

Comment: It would seem like your current entry definition should be imported. Do you want to have multiple entry points that exist under containers or components?

Comment: I think that every file in the modules should be referenced either directly by an app.js import or through a reference from another file. The project is derived from the react-boilerplate repo but I having to build a new webpack config to resolve why some references are not being included.

Answer (score 2):

```
resolve: {
     modules: ['app', 'node_modules'],
     extensions: ['.js']
},
```

appears to work.

Comment: Why? Explaination please?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but it does work. I think that `node_modules` is the only default. So this specifies the `app` directory as the root for all modules   and you have to add `node_modules` as you're not using the default anymore. For the record, all my JSX files are just with a .js extension.